# Saving Files in Folder using information in CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV File, with various Columns.

2 columns are of my interest

Data -

```
     file_Id            name
0          1     Distrustful
1          4         Ashamed
2          5       Depressed
3          6         Worried
4          7        Convinced

[767 rows x 2 columns]
```

The File_ID is actually the name of files without extensions, (i.e. 1.wav, 4.wav, and so on) all saved in a particular folder.

I want a python script to run over the dataframe, go to the `file_Id`, add the extension, and then save it in a directory with a name corresponding to the value under the `name` column, create the directory if it doesn't exist.

Example -

1.wav is saved in Distrustful

4.wav in Ashamed and so on

My Attempt -

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Data.csv')
df1 = df.sort_values(['name', 'file_Id'])
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['Arousal', 'Valence', 'closest_pairs', 'min_distance'])
print (df1)
```

Result -

```
               song_Id
name                  
Ambitious           28
Ashamed             45
Attentive            1
Bored                1
Confident            5
Convinced           85
..       ...        ...
```

I actually now have no clue, aboout how i shall proceed, `os.splitext` was my first guess but its not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Path to create [*pythonic* path objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which make it easy to create directories, add extensions, etc. Then use the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html) module to efficiently copy the files.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2

# Path with files
source = Path("source/path")

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # Convert to string and then create file path (without extension)
    filename = Path(str(row["file_Id"])).with_suffix(".png")

    # Target folder path
    target = Path(row["name"])

    # Create target folder
    target.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    # Copy file
    copy2(source / filename, target / filename)
```

There's of course a few ways in which you could make this more efficient. Probably get all unique target directories and create those before iterating over all the dataframe rows to copy the files.

Comment: This throws an error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Study\\1`

Is this happening caused the files in the directory already have a .wav extension with them?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you question. Do you have a directory of files with extensions and want to re-organize the files to be under the correct directory? I edited my answer to reflect that the files already have extensions in their original folder.

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't clear, I have a folder which has over 750 songs (each is wav file), the file_Id in the dataframe are the names of the files, so I have files like 1.wav, 4.wav etc. Now what I want to do is, make a new directory according to the name column in the dataframe and copy/move song to that directory. Hopefully, this makes it clear

Comment: Thank you so much. I will just change a few things here and there. This is perfect for my case.

Answer (score 0):

```python
import pandas
import shutil
import os

file = pandas.read_csv('trial.csv') #This is just an example

id = file.iloc[0:, 0]
folder = file.iloc[0:, 1]

real_path = os.getcwd() #Gets the current working directory

for i in range(len(folder)): #Since both id and folders have the same total number of variables.
    old_id = str(id[i]) #i.e, '0'
    old_id_path = real_path + '\\' + old_id #i.e, 'C:\Windows\0'

    new_id = str(id[i]) + '.wav' #i.e, '0.wav'
    new_id_path = real_path + '\\' + new_id #i.e, 'C:\Windows\0.wav'

    new_folder = real_path + '\\' + folder[i] #i.e, 'C:\Windows\noise

    destination_file = new_folder + '\\' + new_id #i.e, 'C:\Windows\noise\0.wav'


if os.path.exists(destination_file) == True or os.path.exists(old_id_path) == False:
 #if the file is already in destination or doesn't exist at all
    continue #Skip this loop

if os.path.exists(new_id) == True: #i.e, if 'C:\Windows\0.wav' exists
    pass
else:
    shutil.move(old_id_path, new_id_path) #i.e, renames the 0 to 0.wav
    
if os.path.exists(new_folder) == True: #i.e, if 'C:\Windows\noise' exists
    pass
else:
    os.makedirs(new_folder) #creates the new folder, i.e, 'C:\Windows\noise'
    
shutil.move(new_id_path, destination_file) #moves the file to the destination
#i.e, 0.wav to noise, 'C:\Windows\noise\0.wav'
```